# Drag-n-Drop JTableHeader

Tags: java, swing, jtable, drag-and-drop, jtableheader

I'm using `JTable` + `JScrollPane` + `DefaultTableModel`.

I need to implement Drag-n-Drop on `JTableHeader`. I want to drag a column header to my component and do some work depending on the column dragged.

I've tried `setTransferHandler()` on my `JTableHeader` but dragging is still not working.

Where can I start? Is it possible to implement DnD on `JTableHeader` and save the "move-columns" feature (available 'out-of-the-box' in `JTable`)?

Comment: Specify "not working": you cannot initiate a drag (not even the move-columns), you can move columns but not drop on your component, you can  drag-and-drop but the drop is not doing what you expected, ...

Comment: I can rearrange columns but I can't initiate a drag (cursor is not changing, drop-methods of my component does not fire on mouse-button-release)

Comment: you may consider to put your update as an answer to your question (and accept it), easier to find for future users with the signal "solved" :-)

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra . Too bad I can accept my own answer only after 2 days. Will check it later.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**: Question closed. I've implemented dnd using

```
DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(tableHeader, ...)
```

One thing to mention: dnd breaks default 'rearrange columns' behavior. My workaround was

```
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        if (dge.getDragAction() == DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY)
            return;
        try {
            dge.startDrag(null, new MyTransferable());
        } catch (InvalidDnDOperationException e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
```

so that I can rearrange columns with ctrl-pressed. It's enough for me.